# Internally calling a salesforce web service that lies inside a managed package

Tags: apex, rest-api, webservices, callout

I'm developing an application where my code will make a Http POST request to a web service lying in my org.

As of now, this is what I'm doing:

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
Http http = new Http();

req.setEndpoint(Constants.SF_BASE_URL + '/services/apexrest/peer/v2/loanAccounts/setupACH/' + (String)contract.get('Id')); // http://ap4.salesforce.com/......
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());

Map<String, String> urlParams = new Map<String, String>();
urlParams.put(..., ...); // about 10 of these of these

System.PageReference pageReference = new System.PageReference('');
pageReference.getParameters().putAll(urlParams);
String query = pageReference.getUrl().substringAfter('?'); // to get the url encoded query

req.setBody(query);
req.setTimeout(20000);

res = http.send(req);
```

I figured out how to do this after many painful hours of searching the web. Everyone tells you how to create a web service, but no one will tell you how to call it, especially from salesforce.

Anyway, when I try and run this code, I get an error saying

> Unauthorized endpoint, please check Setup->Security->Remote site settings. endpoint = https://ap4.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/peer/v2/loanAccounts/setupACH/a6E6F00000001nrUAA

I can't create a Remote Site Settings entry because the URL is likely to change as my code could run on different instances.

Is there any alternative way I can make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The address you need to whitelist in your `Remote Site Settings` is just the instance:

```
https://ap4.salesforce.com
```

Once you whitelist that, internal API calls should work just fine.

Comment: That's good news! Can I do this via code? Preferably some code to check for an entry before actually making the callout. I don't want someone to manually do it every time the instance changes.

Comment: Do your instances change often? You'd have to resort to Javascript if you want to go the code route, as any `Apex` callouts depend on the instance itself already being whitelisted.

Comment: No but my code is going to possibly reside on different instances. Plus when testing we test in different orgs, so the instance and/or the base URL could be different.

Comment: See also: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/169382/2995

Comment: Alright, one last thing. Is there an alternative way to make the WS call without whitelisting or tooling?

Comment: You can just reference the `Apex` directly...why do you need it to be a webservice in the first place?

Comment: Because, if I were to reference it directly I'd have to specify that package as a dependency to mine, which I'm not supposed to do. So a ws is the only way out :)